# Trigger.old is Throwing an error While i am adding addError method to show the error

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

```
trigger RestrictHindiTeacher on Teach__c(before insert, before update) {
    if(trigger.IsInsert){
        for(Teach__c c : trigger.new){
            if(c.subject__c.contains('Hindi')){
                c.subject__c.addError('Sorry Hindi teachers can not create the account');
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        for(Teach__c c : trigger.old){
            if(c.subject__c.contains('Hindi')){
                c.addError('Sorry Hindi teachers can not update the account');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**When subject is Hindi record can not be updated **that's my concern

Please help how I can solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the addError method for only those records that are avaliable in Trigger Context .
I think we can use Trigger.newMap for before insert and before update. and Trigger.oldMap for before delete

`trigger RestrictHindiTeacher on Teach__c(before insert, before update) {
    if(trigger.IsInsert){
        for(Teach__c c : trigger.new){
            if(c.subject__c.contains('Hindi')){
                c.subject__c.addError('Sorry Hindi teachers can not create the account');
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        for(Teach__c c : trigger.old){
            if(c.subject__c.contains('Hindi')){
              Teach__c actualRecord= trigger.newMap.get(c.Id);
               actualRecord.adderror('Sorry Hindi teachers can not update the account');
            }
        }
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the else part. Try below.

```
trigger RestrictHindiTeacher on Teach__c(before insert, before update) {
if(trigger.IsInsert || trigger.IsUpdate){
    for(Teach__c c : trigger.new){
        if(c.subject__c.contains('Hindi')){
            c.addError('Sorry Hindi teachers can not create the account');
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: But in this case, if I update the field of Teach__c then it will not show any error. I want that for all Hindi related cases it restrict to create and update

Comment: It will throw an error , that's why we are using trigger.IsUpdate in the OR condition. Why don't you give a try and see what it gives.

Comment: c.addError('Sorry Hindi teachers can not update the account');
But this line is always throwing an exception, Is there any alternative to print the error on UI

Comment: Updated my answer. adderror() is always called in the trigger's record context. But it seems you were using in the field context c.subject__c.addError('Sorry Hindi teachers can not create the account'); which is incorrect

Comment: @gopal :- If that resolves your error message. Can you close this thread by selecting an answer.